# adding UILabel in Objective-C, change Background Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I add a UILabel using objective c, have a white rectagle around them.  How do I remove this rectangle so the background shows through? 
I looked in the documnetion for uilabel view and did not see anything per to background.
code

```
UILabel *mContact=[ [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(273,442,32,20)];
mContact.text=@"Contact";
mContact.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9.0 ];
[self.view addSubview:mContact];
```

-Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

--or--

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whateverColorYouWant];
```

Also, check out the [UILabel Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/UILabel_Class.pdf)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the easy fix, seems like the backgrouncolor is in the UIView, which UILabel inheris from, I did not think of that.

Answer (score 2):

`UILabel` has a background property it inherits from `UIView`, set it to clear:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor

mContact.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[mContact setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];
//or
mContact.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```